# Recover original MP3 from decoded WAV

Tags: audio-conversion

I have a CD that was made from an MP3 source. I have since lost the original source. Is it possible to reconstruct the original source from the decompressed audio on the CD, the goal being to save room and avoid the further loss of a second MP3 encoding?

I know I can’t use a regular encoding algorithm. I’m wondering if a special algorithm could be used to determine how the WAV was originally compressed and restore that particular MP3 source file, minus tags, metadata, etc…

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the output.

If you need to make it an MP3, then the answer is always no.

The reason is as follows: MP3 is a compressed format that is made by applying an algorithm to the source in order to calculate how it is going to be compressed. If you save an MP3, it is always compressed. When you compress an MP3 into an MP3 the second MP3 will not be identical to the first MP3.

Instead, it will be a processed file meaning that there will be a quality loss even if its not that noticeable.

However, if you don't mind it being a wav, then you can do with it whatever you want and the quality will remain the same. Saving a Wav to a Wav will mean that they are identical.

So you mention you have an MP3 rip of a cd, which was converted to a Wav and now you want to turn it back into an MP3 version. This will cause for quality loss. It is better to recreate an MP3 version of a high quality version of the CD. Keep in mind, that in order to do this, you need to actually own the CD, otherwise it is illegal.

If you do not own the cd, then simply buy the MP3 version.

If you owned the cd version once but you lost it or it got damaged, then keep in mind, that if you own a bike and you lose it, you can't just steal a bike and its okay, because hey, I owned a similar bike once! Its theft.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. I know I can't use a regular algorithm. I'm wondering if a special algorithm could be used to determine how the wav was originally compressed and restore that particular MP3.

Comment: And real life objects are very poor analogues to data. I can copy data at almost zero cost. Can you copy your bike? Therefore the usual rules of ownership and theft simply don't apply, no matter what the RIAA says. All that matters is that the artists are fairly compensated for their work—a condition decidedly disconnected from the number of copies of their work get sold, especially after the ~95% publishers' overhead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to reconstruct the original source from the
>   decompressed audio on the CD, the goal being to save room and avoid
>   the further loss of a second MP3 encoding?

Not exactly.

MP3 is an lossy format. When you made it a CD, it took your MP3 data and basically decompressed it as is into the uncompressed data stored on the CD.

Your only choice now is to re-encode the MP3 from the CD. If you use standard MP3 encoding options, you will get a VBR (Variable Bit Rate) MP3 based on the CD. But if you explicitly export the CD as a CBR (Constant Bit Rate) MP3 encoded at 320kbps that will come pretty close to being an exact copy of the CD with a very minimal loss of quality due to transcoding/recompression.